# Navigation from one view to another in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, navigation

I wrote code which should navigate between user controls in WPF application using MVVM, but I realised that this code doesn't work. 
From window `LoginView` I want to change the view to `VotingCardView`.

Actually, after clicking on the button in the `LoginView`, the method `DisplayVCV` gets executed, but the view is not going to change. What am I doing wrong?

MainView.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ElectionCalculator.View.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ElectionCalculator"
        xmlns:v="clr-namespace:ElectionCalculator.View"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ElectionCalculator.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Election calculator" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModel}" />
</Window>
```

LoginView.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ElectionCalculator.View.LoginView"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ElectionCalculator.View"
      xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ElectionCalculator.ViewModel"

      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <Grid>
        <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.DisplayVC, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="161,147,47,124" />
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public BaseViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
    }

    public ICommand DisplayVC { get { return new RelayCommand(DisplayVCV); } }

    public void DisplayVCV()
    {
        ViewModel = new VotingCardViewModel();

        MessageBox.Show("DisplayVCCommandExecuted");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ViewModel` property implementation doesn't raise a `PropertyChanged` event when the value changes. This is usually done via an [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) implementation. Because of that, your view doesn't get notified that something has changed.

In your case, this means that you need a backing field for your `ViewModel` property and implement your `ViewModel` property similar to this:

```
private BaseViewModel _viewModel;
public BaseViewModel ViewModel
{
  get { return _viewModel; }
  set
  {
    if(_viewModel != value) 
    {
      _viewModel = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("ViewModel");
    }
  }
}
```

Since you are already deriving from `BaseViewModel` I assume that the method `OnPropertyChanged` (or some method with a similar name) is implemented there. It is also quite common that you don't have to specify the property name (`"ViewModel"`) as an argument, since lots of implementations use the [`[CallerMemberName]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute for this purpose.